# c++ swapping array elements by moving, not copying

Tags: c++, arrays

Is it possible to swap two elements of an array by simply moving both to the new index instead of a costly copy with a temp value?

I have this code:

```
struct Piece {
    int index;
    int type;
    int square;

    Piece() {}
    ~Piece() {}
    Piece(Piece& piece) {
        printf("copy");
    }
    Piece(Piece&& piece) {
        printf("move");
    }

    void operator=(Piece& piece) {
        printf("copy1");
        int temp = square;
        square = piece.square;
        piece.square = temp;
    }
    void operator=(Piece&& piece) {
        printf("move1");
    }
};

int main() {
    Piece* pieces = new Piece[10];
    Piece* sliders = new Piece[10];

    pieces[0] = {};
    pieces[0].square = 50;
    pieces[1] = {};
    pieces[1].square = 20;

    Piece temp = pieces[0];
    pieces[0] = pieces[1];
    pieces[1] = temp;

    cout << pieces[1].square << " " << pieces[0].square;
    char test;
    cin >> test;
}
```

This always prints "move" when initializing and "copy1" when swapping with temp.
Is there any way to do the same by moving, without using an array of pointers?

Please ignore the bad style of this code.

Comment: Why do you think that is "costly"?  Do you have any kind of numbers to back that up?  Do you think the software is too stupid to optimize it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `std::swap`...

```
std::swap(pieces[0], pieces[1]);
```

You could equivalently write:

```
Piece temp = std::move(pieces[0]);
pieces[0] = std::move(pieces[1]);
pieces[1] = std::move(temp);
```

but `std::swap` is more concise.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: Use std::swap.

```
std::swap<Piece>(pieces[0], pieces[1])
```

Option 2: Use std::move.

```
Piece temp = std::move(pieces[0]);
pieces[0] = std::move(pieces[1]);
pieces[1] = std::move(temp);
```

Moreover, make your move operations non throwing.

Comment: The `std::move()` should not actually do anything for his Piece class.

Comment: You don't need to specify the template parameter explicitly, the compiler can infer it from the input parameters: `std::swap(pieces[0], pieces[1]);`. `std::swap()` uses move semantics when possible. So really, if `Piece` supports moving, the STL will implement option 1 in terms of option 2. So always favor option 1 in code.

Answer (score 2):

Since your class' data is simply a few scalar values, it actually doesn't matter whether you swap them through a temporary. That is, it won't matter if you drop the calls to printing code, and if you optimize your compilation. It'll all happen via registers anyway.

You should still use [`std::swap()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) though, since it's the "right way" to do it. And if you ever make your Piece class more involved, it'll actually have some effect...

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to swap two elements of an array by simply moving both to the new index instead of a costly copy with a temp value?

No for given struct Piece. You benefit from move semantics, when you can assign (copy, swap) pointer to data of big size and/or heap-allocated. The savings come from copying pointer instead of larger data and/or from avoiding memory freeing/allocation, which may take even more CPU cycles, than copying large data object.